# Postfix Package Openarc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, milter

I have a server running Ubuntu 16.  I'm trying to get postfix configured to use OpenArc.

I've installed the OpenArc package, but it's not automatically starting on reboot.

If I run

```
openarc -c /etc/openarc/openarc.conf -n
```

it doesn't return an error.  /etc/openarc/openarc.conf is as follows:

```
AuthservID mi domain
Domain mi domain
KeyFile /etc/opendkim/keys/201901.private
Selector 201901
Mode sv
Socket inet:8895@localhost
SoftwareHeader yes
Syslog Yes
UserID opendkim
AutoRestart yes
PidFile /var/run/opendkim/openarc.pid
```

If I run

```
openarc -c /etc/openarc/openarc.conf
```

It tells me the milter is busy.

When I run `lsof -i | grep openarc` it reports:

```
openarc  10849 opendkim   7u  IPv4 160111      0t0 TCP localhost: 8895-> localhost: 44132 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I've also configured postfix to access the milter by adding to /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtpd_milters = inet: localhost: 8891, inet: localhost: 8892, inet: localhost: 8895
non_smtpd_milters = inet: localhost: 8891, inet : localhost: 8892, inet: localhost: 8895
```

But when postfix tries to use it, it reports

```
postfix / smtpd [1396]: warning: connect to Milter service inet: localhost: 8895: Connection refused
```

Please let me know what else you may need to know to help me with my problem.  Thank you very much.

---

gracias por intentar ayudarme pese a que no se entiende el idioma .. mi idioma nativo es el español .. mira cuando reinicio la maquina ... el openarc no se ejecuta .. pero si ... pongo el codigo .. openarc -c /etc/openarc/openarc.conf -n se ejecuta ... te paso el contenido de mi openarc.conf...

```
AuthservID mi domain
Domain mi domain
KeyFile /etc/opendkim/keys/201901.private
Selector 201901
Mode sv
Socket inet:8895@localhost
SoftwareHeader yes
Syslog Yes
UserID opendkim
AutoRestart yes
PidFile /var/run/opendkim/openarc.pid
```

al hacer `lsoft-i` me da el resultado:

```
openarc 10849 opendkim 7u IPv4 160111 0t0 TCP localhost:8895->localhost:44132 (ESTABLISHED)
```

pero una vez que cargo el openarc.conf ... me da el resultado de que esta conectado el milter .. se me entiende?

otra cosa que hice fue poner el milter en el main.cf ... de esta manera ... smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891, inet:localhost:8892, inet:localhost:8895 non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891, inet:localhost:8892, inet:localhost:8895

pero al iniciar si no pongo el openarc -c .. no me abre y me salta error ..postfix/smtpd[2174]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:localhost:8895: Connection refused

---

I raised the openarc once I put the comomando to load the milter .. it would be really load the openarc.conf .. file as follows

**`openarc -c /etc/openarc/openarc.conf -n`**

Y:

**`openarc -c /etc/openarc/openarc.conf`**

*when I put this the milter loads me and the openarc walks me ... but it throws me error that the milter is busy .. but I have nothing but the openarc in that milter ...*

**postfix / smtpd [1396]: warning: connect to Milter service inet: localhost: 8895: Connection refused**

It's the first time I write a problem with postfix I do not know if they need to see other files to help me ... thank you very much ...

Comment: I'm trying to understand your post, but it's difficult.  I've looked at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8162/we-need-to-help-non-english-speakers-somehow for some ideas. Would it be possible for you to also include an explanation of your issue in your native language? I won't be able to understand that, but I will be able to plug it into various online translation programs and possibly get something I can understand better.

Comment: As far as other information necessary to solve this problem... the contents of /etc/openarc/openarc.conf could be helpful, especially the Socket setting. Also, if you run `ps -ef|grep openarc`, does it show that openarc is running?

Comment: gracias por intentar ayudarme pese a que no se entiende el idioma .. mi idioma nativo es el español .. mira cuando reinicio la maquina ... el openarc no se ejecuta .. pero si ... pongo el codigo .. `openarc -c /etc/openarc/openarc.conf -n` se ejecuta ... te paso el contenido de mi openarc.conf...

Comment: `AuthservID              mi domain....
Domain                  mi domain....
KeyFile                 /etc/opendkim/keys/201901.private.....
Selector                201901.....
Mode                    sv......
Socket                  inet:8895@localhost.....
SoftwareHeader  yes.....
Syslog                  Yes.....
UserID          opendkim........
AutoRestart             yes........
PidFile                 /var/run/opendkim/openarc.pid`...........

Comment: al hacer lsoft-i me da el resultado:  **openarc   10849  opendkim    7u  IPv4 160111      0t0  TCP localhost:8895->localhost:44132 (ESTABLISHED)**

Comment: pero una vez que cargo el openarc.conf ... me da el resultado de que esta conectado el milter .. se me entiende?

Comment: otra cosa que hice fue poner el milter en el main.cf ... de esta manera ... 
                                                                                                      
            `smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891, inet:localhost:8892, inet:localhost:8895
                                                                                               
                                                                                               
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891, inet:localhost:8892, inet:localhost:8895
`

Comment: pero al iniciar si no pongo el openarc -c .. no me abre y me salta error `..postfix/smtpd[2174]: warning: connect to Milter service inet:localhost:8895: Connection refused`

Comment: I apologize; I did not communicate well. I expected you to add this detail to the question using the edit button, so formatting would be preserved. Me disculpo; No me comuniqué bien. Esperaba que agregara este detalle a la pregunta usando el botón de edición, por lo que se conservaría el formato.

Comment: At first, it sounds like openarc is not restarting on boot, but later it sounds like you run `openarc -c /etc/openarc/openarc.conf` and are told the milter is busy. Is that right? Al principio, parece que openarc no se está reiniciando en el arranque, pero luego parece que ejecutas `openarc -c / etc / openarc / openarc.conf` y se te dice que el milter está ocupado. ¿Está bien?

Comment: Yes, that exactly .. si eso mismo

Comment: necesitaria .. ponerlo en el inicio .. no se esta iniciando junto con el ubuntu 16....I would need to ... put it in the beginning .. it is not getting started together with the ubuntu 16

Comment: I have tried.  I can't figure this out.  I have also tried to work up an edit to make this question more legible to other English speakers who may  know more about this issue. Yo he tratado. No puedo entender esto. También he intentado elaborar una edición para que esta pregunta sea más legible para otros hablantes de inglés que puedan saber más sobre este problema.

Comment: desde ya muchas gracias x la ayuda no sabia como hacer para editarlo bien ...since thank you very much x the help did not know how to edit it well ...

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this in your /etc/postfix/main.cf:

`inet: localhost: 8891, inet : localhost: 8892, inet: localhost: 8895`

instead be like this:

`inet:localhost:8891,inet:localhost:8892,inet:localhost:8895`